# appending another transform to existing properties

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to append new transform property to existing properties?

For example: I have a `div.animation`, which has the following definition

```
.animation {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Now I want to append `transform: scale(1)` to the same element:

```
.animation.active {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Obviously if I do that, it will override translateX and translateY properties. Is there any way to be able to append another transform property without overriding - the same way as you can do it with border-left and other CSS attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There's no subproperties to [**transform**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

To append multiple transforms you'd need to repeat the previous ones:

```
.animation {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.animation.active {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1);
}
```